# What does this error mean in Rails: "Errno::ENOENT in AssetsController#get ...No such file or directory...."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

Im writing an app to store files on Amazon S3. Im pretty close, Im able to save and retrieve files using a url. However since these links are public Im trying to use the following method in my assetscontroller to retrieve stored files from S3.

As links these files can be viewed/accessed in the browser, but if I use this code :

```
#This action will let the users download the files (after a simple authorization check)
def get
  asset = current_user.assets.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if asset
  #Parse the URL for special characters first before downloading  
  data = open("#{URI.parse(URI.encode(asset.uploaded_file.url))}")
  #then again, use the "send_data" method to send the above binary "data" as file.  
   send_data data, :filename => asset.uploaded_file_file_name 

 else
   flash[:error]="Access Violation"
   redirect_to assets_path
 end
```

end

Im getting this error in my browser:

```
Errno::ENOENT in AssetsController#get
No such file or directory - http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/assets/29/FILENAME.jpeg?    1339979591
```

When I click on the resource on the S3 site as Im logged into the S3 management console, the file is shown in my browser and its link is

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/assets/29/FILENAME.jpeg?     AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXExpires=1340003832&Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-amz-security-      token=XXXXXXXXX//////////XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So it does exist but cant be accessed through my app

Here is my Application Trace from my browser:

```
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:99:in `initialize'
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:99:in `open'
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:99:in `get'
```

Any clues on whats going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also just redirect the user to the file on S3.

Just try

```
redirect_to asset.uploaded_file.url
```

instead of `send_file`. `send_file` expects a path to a local file, which is then used by the webserver.

If you've set `s3_permissions => :private`, then you need to call

```
redirect_to asset.uploaded_file.expiring_url(10)
```

It's also interesting that in your error message it is http against https in s3 - you can also try to add the following option to your model's has_attached_file

```
:s3_protocol => 'https'
```

Hope this helps.